# Why there is different inradius between Icosahedron and Truncated Icosahedron?

Tags: geometry

We consider the edge's length of the icosahedron is 1 unit.
We have an inradius of Icosahedron **r_icosa =~ 0.75**
while we have an inradius of Truncated Icosahedron: **r_trunIcosa =~ 2.265**

And we have two other different distances from centre of the Truncated Icosahedron to pentagon/hexagon faces center.

As my understanding, truncated icosahedron is generated from icosahedron where the vertices of icosahedron are cut to generate pentagons. So the distance from the center of icosahedron will be same as the distance from center of truncated icosahedron. But from these theories, they are different.

It would be great if anyone can help to explain that. Thanks so much.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularIcosahedron.html

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedron.html

Comment: What happens to the edge lengths when you cut off the vertices of an icosahedron?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the edge lengths will be reduced. But, for example, the diameter from the bottom and the top of the icosahedron and truncated icosahedron is the same. Then the inradius ( inscribed sphere) will be the same?

Comment: So when you say that r_trunIcosa =~ 2.265, what is the unit length? Is it the length of the original icosahedron edge or the new shorter edge length?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks for your comments and question. I got the answer. r_icosa =~ 0.75a while an inradius of Truncated Icosahedron: r_trunIcosa =~ 2.265b. It will be the same if a=3b. However, I don't know why distance from the inradius of truncated icosahedron differs from distance from centre to pentagon faces and hexagons faces.

Comment: In a truncated icosahedron, the planes cutting out the pentagons are 
not chosen to have same distance as the inradius of underlying icosahedron. Instead, they are chosen to make the hexagons regular polygon (ie. cutting at the $\frac13$ and $\frac23$ points of edges of icosahedron).

Comment: Where did you get the formula for the inradius of the truncated icosahedron?

Comment: @achillehui thanks for your great comments. I now understand the different distances. However, when we say Inradius for truncated icosahedron, the sphere needs to contact the hexagon faces? if so, the Inradius has equal to the distance from centre of the solid to the hexagon faces.

Comment: @AlanAbraham You can check the link I posted!

Comment: @LAMNGOCTAM However, the website gives no formula for the inradius of the truncated polyhedra, so I'm not sure where you got it. It does give the formula for the distance from the centroid of each of the faces to the center, but since those distances are different an inradius does not exist.

Comment: @AlanAbraham In the website: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedron.html   we can see r. r5 and r6 are the three different distances and r is the inradius of a truncated icosahedron. The same result for r at https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/t/t405.htm

Comment: The mathworld website gives $r\approx 2.37713$, while you have declared a different value. Moreover, the mathworld website says that $r$ is the inradius of the dual polyhedron of the truncated icosahedron, not of the truncated icosahedron itself.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Oh, thanks for your comment. My mistake is to see r≈2.37713 is the inradius of the truncated icosahedron.  Do you have information on the inradius of the truncated icosahedron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a truncated icosahedron is formed by truncating the vertices so that the side length of the regular hexagonal faces is the same as that of the regular pentagonal faces, we can see that the sidelength of the truncated icosahedron must be $\frac{1}{3}$ that of the icosahedron that generated it.

We are given from [mathworld-icosahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularIcosahedron.html) that the inradius of a unit icosahedron is $\approx 0.755$

We can also see from [mathworld-truncated icosahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedron.html) that the distance from the center of the polyhedron to the center of the pentagonal and hexagonal faces are respectively
$$r_5 \approx 2.327$$
$$r_6 \approx 2.267$$

Note that upon dividing these by $3$ to get the respective values corresponding to the truncated icosahedron generated from a unit icosahedron, we get values of
$$r_5' \approx 0.775$$
$$r_6' \approx 0.755$$

Note that both of these values are close to the inradius of a unit icosahedron, which is reasonable. Moreover, $r_6'$ is exactly the same as the inradius of a unit icosahedron. This makes sense because the hexagonal faces generated from truncating were generated from the triangular faces and hence have the same centers.

Since the inradius of a polyhedron is defined as the radius of the inscribed sphere. And the inscribed sphere is defined as the sphere which is tangent to all faces, it is evident that there does not exist an inscribed sphere because the pentagonal faces are a different distance from the center as the hexagonal faces.

However, if you were looking for the radius of the largest sphere that could fit inside the truncated icosahedron, it would be $r_6'\approx .755$ because $r_6'<r_5'$. Hence, if you were blowing up a sphere inside the truncated icosahedron, it would first make contact with the hexagonal faces before making contact with the pentagonal faces.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas in wolfram have a factor a=length of side
if you truncate an icosaeder with a=1, the length of the new    sides is much shorter.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Would you please explain there are three different distances from center of Truncated icosahedron to Hexagon faces, pentagon faces and inradius?